# have composer install wordpress and symfony2

Tags: wordpress, symfony, composer-php

Using Composer, i am trying to get symfony2 installed in a directory, and wordpress in another.

Using info found here http://roots.io/using-composer-with-wordpress/ i figured i could just edit my sf2 composer.json and add the required info, but no luck.

Is this possible, or should i create another composer.json file in the subdirectory ?

For reference, here is the (simplified) json:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "wordpress",
                "type": "webroot",
                "version": "3.8",
                "dist": {
                    "type": "zip",
                    "url": "https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/archive/3.8.zip"
                },
                "require" : {
                    "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",

        "wordpress": "3.8",
        "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
    },

    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        },

        "webroot-dir": "wp",
        "webroot-package": "wordpress"
    }
}
```

The error i get is:

```
symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev requires wordpress 3.8 -> no matching package found
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this !

Comment: Your composer.json works perfectly fine for me. Try updating composer.

Comment: Indeeed you are right, i was trying to use composer install with an outdated lock file, which resulted in the error. Thanks !